# Which preposition goes with "get feedback on/about something "

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which of the prepositions is correct in the following case:

1. [...] where I can get direct feedback on my lab work
2. [...] where I can get direct feedback about my lab work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both **on** and **about** are valid here. A [Google N-grams search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get+feedback+on%2Cgive+feedback+on%2Cget+feedback+about%2Cgive+feedback+about&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cget%20feedback%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgive%20feedback%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cget%20feedback%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgive%20feedback%20about%3B%2Cc0) suggests **on** is a bit more common.